# How to select the value from drop down present on pop-up

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver

I click on the link and get the pop-up and on that pop-up their is a drop down.
My question is how to select the value from drop down present on pop-up.

Below is html :

```
<select onchange="formsubmit()" id="selectedchannel" name="selectedchannel">
                    <option value="521">Abec</option>
                    <option value="3322">Abdwdc</option>
                    <option value="1463">Abfc</option>
                    <option value="3849">Abdfc</option>
                    <option value="960">Abdfc</option>
                   </select>
```

Comment: Yes .... pop-up is iframe

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So first you have to switch to frame and then can select value.

Select specific value in this way :

```
driver.switchTo().frame(0); // Here 0 is index of frame , you can switch to frame by it's name also. i.e  driver.switchTo().frame("your frame name");

Select option = new Select (driver.findElement(By.id("selectedchannel")));
option.selectByVisibleText("Abec");
```

You can select option by any of these 3 options :

```
option.selectByVisibleText("") // it can be Abdfc,Abec etc.

option.selectByIndex(index) // it can be 0 ,1,2 etc

option.selectByValue(value); //it can be 521,960 etc.
```